# No console window shown in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

If I create a new console application (.NET Framework 4.5.2) and enter the following lines as the complete contents of the Main method:

```
Console.WriteLine("A");
Console.ReadLine();
```

When I hit run (F5), VS enters debugging mode and shows the memory usage graph  but does not show any console window. This same problem is seen on every console application I try to use in VS2017. While not universally the case, in the app I described above, running this by double-clicking the .exe file does produce a console window.

Does anyone know how to get VS2017 to show a console window?

Comment: Nothing that a disk format could not solve.  Do check that the console window is not *behind* the VS window.

Comment: @Hans_Passant it's definitely not hiding there 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be to do with 32-bit applications.
Unticking the prefer 32-bit option in the build options solves the problem.

---

**Edit:** Further investigation showed this to be a problem with an extension used within my company. Disabling this extension let my console windows appear again.

Comment: I just came across this issue, unticking it seems to solve the problem but any ideas why? Seems kind of weird to me.

Comment: I wish I knew. I think the problem existed in 2015 but was solved by using the hosting process. Vs2017 doesn't have the hosting process so this is the only option I've found